# Error Using JODA-Time Library

Tags: android, jodatime

I've used joda-time library using

`compile files('libs/joda-time-2.9.3.jar')`

I can compile and run my apk on Android version 5 or higher but when I want to compile it for Android version 4 I get this error:

> Could not find class 'org.joda.time.TimeOfDay', referenced from method
>   org.joda.time.DateTime.toTimeOfDay

Comment: By the way, jar file is not necessary. `compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.9.4'`

Comment: the problem is which method i used the program wont compile on api 17 18 19 !!! for api 21 and greater there is no problem !

Comment: I understand the error. However, I do not know what to tell you. There should be nothing in the joda code that prevents it from compiling in a specific API version

Comment: but in another application i don't have any error and the joda-time library work fine on android version 4.0 i really get confused here!!